# Disable Scrollbar in Cordova iOS

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

i want to disable the Scrollbar in my iOS App. The Content should be scrollable, but the scrollbar should be invisible.

How can i realize this?

Comment: show me some code or UI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other answer is great and perfect (as far as I know) for most browsers. However, if you were just targeting iOS and/or Android, this CSS would be simpler, sufficient, and requires no structural changes to your HTML:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

I just tested this myself. Works with webkit browsers, which means it'll work for Android/iOS.

Comment: Look for this answer in loads of places, this is the only thing that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this first `overflow-y: hidden;` will hide both the scroll bar and then `overflow-y: scroll;` will allow to scroll vertically.

CSS

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#scrollable {
   height: 150px;   
   width: 218px;
   overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="scrollable">
         <!--Content goes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me as of 2020 so here's what fixed it for me:

Apply

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Where you would like to hide the scrollbar